# Botón en HTML que te envíe a otra página

Tags: html, html5

¿Cómo puedo hacer un boton que me envíe a otra página que yo le especifique? Hasta ahora solo he sabido hacerlo con la etiqueta `<a>` y su atributo href y target. Pero no consigo hacerlo con un `<button>`.

Comment: Por favor deja de regresar las ediciones a la versión original, solo quitamos la información que no es necesaria (saludos y etc) y mejoramos el formato, además de mejorar la ortografía y redacción.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo así:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>

  </style>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="location.href='https://www.facebook.com'">Llévame a otro lado</button>
</body>
</html>
```

No ocupas nada de la etiqueta a, pero gracias a location.href le indica la dirección a la cual quieres llegar

Comment: Me gusta tu forma de hacerlo. Con el onclick estas utilizando javascript noo?

Comment: Osea que el onclick es algo propio del button, no hay nada de JS?

Comment: al ser botón, es por su propia naturaleza cliqueable; a lo que voy no es que no use JS me refiero a que para lograr el punto ue planteas me valgo de una propiedad que tienen los botones en HTML

Comment: A eso me referia. Que el evento onclick es algo propio del boton de HTML.

Comment: No estas usando por tanto nada de JS jeje

Comment: location es un objeto propio del navegador , lo puedes comprobar al escribir en la consola asi solito location y de hecho te lo auto completa asi que asi es tienes razón

Comment: Genial! Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: Perdon una ultima duda. Como puedo poner dentro de ese boton que la pagina se abriera en otra pagina? Se que es con target= _blank pero no se donde colocarlo :S

Comment: Saludos solo lo logré de este modo mira <button onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com','_blank')">Llévame al Face</button>

Comment: De acuerdo! Muchas gracias de nuevo!

Comment: Bien la respuesta, pero muy mal los comentarios. El código `onclick="location.href='...'"` **SI ES JS**, y el atributo onclick [no es una propiedad del botón](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick), sino que lo tienen **ABSOLUTAMENTE TODOS** los elementos HTML. Podés vincular el comando `location.href='...'` literalmente a **cualquier elemento HTML** de tu página.

Comment: Adicionalmente, **es JS** ya que la variable `location` es una [propiedad de la ventana](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/location) como objeto del DOM, accesible al JS como variable global (a través de `window.location`) y el atributo `href` define la ruta de la ventana. Por tanto, cambiar la propiedad `href` del objeto, redirige la ventana actual (o el objeto de ventana instanciado) a la ruta que se está asignando.

Comment: si, gracias por el comentario @Niche

Comment: @Sergio te veo con ganas, echa un vistazo a eventos, los hay en todos los lenguajes

Answer (score 1):

Prueba agregando `target="_blank"` a una etiqueta `<a>`

```css
a{
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px 7px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://es.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">Mi boton</a>
```

Comment: target _blank lo unico que hace es abrir el enlace especificado en el href en una nueva pestaña del navegador. No es la solucion que busco pero gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Lo que yo hago es lo siguiente:

```
<a href="destino.php"><input type="button" value="Ir"></a>
```

No sé si será la mejor manera, pero me funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí te dejo otra forma de hacer la redirección;

```css
.button{
height:30px;
width:50px;
background-color:floralwhite;
border-radius:10%;
 }
```

```html
<button name="redirect" class="button" onClick="redirect()">
Click
</button>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    function redirect()
    {
   
    window.location.href="https://programminghead.com/submit-button-redirect-to-another-page-in-html/";
    }
    </script>
```

Utilizamos una pequeña función de *JavaScript* para hacer la redirección de URL.

Como has visto hay diferentes formas de hacerlo, este ejemplo que te he mostrado puede ayudarte a ser más eficiente, por ejemplo, si debes cambiar la redirección eventualmente y tienes diferentes botones en tu web. Para no ir buscando en el código HTML, crea un pequeño archivo *JavaScript* que contenga las redirecciones, cuando las tengas que cambiar, ya lo tienes todo en un mismo documento.

Answer (score -1):

No se si la respuesta es algo tarde. Pero considero por tu pregunta que eres aprendiz, por lo tanto lo ideal seria un codigo como este:

```
<a href="**pagina a redireccionar.php**" class="subir">**Texto del Boton**</a>
```

Comment: si lees la pregunta, el autor sabe hacerlo con a, pero quiere hacerlo con button. Por lo tanto tu respuesta no es válida